# How does Winforms work?

Tags: c#, winforms, terminology

Winforms doesn't use the Model–View–Controller paradigm like wpf. How is it designed then? Does it use another architecture? I want to understand it better.

Comment: This question is waaaay too broad, however for what its worth Windows Forms is a .Net abstraction of the Win32 API. Also WPF doesn't really use the MVC pattern - although the MVVM pattern is fairly popular

Comment: WPF applications usually use Model-View-ViewModel, rather than MVC, but they don't have to. Winforms applications generally don't use a specific paradigm, but I've had success using Model-View-Presenter with them in the past.

Comment: I didn't think there was a difference between WPF and Winforms both have a view and code-behind files its then down to you to implement a model-view-whatever pattern over this.

Comment: @ChrisMoutray: So the Framework has nothing to do with what Model to use? I'm compleatly new to Application Development and want to understand this topic better. It seems this is now the right site to ask such questions.

Comment: You can search for MVC, MVP and MVVM and how they relate. MVP is most suited for WinForms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It calls the InitializeComponent(); to draw all controls on the form.

The call for the InitializeComponent is standard in the form's constructor.

The code within the InitializeComponent method is auto generated by what you are dragging to the form. The size, location, looks, etc of a control gets set there.

Comment: Explaining precisely how Winforms work is way to big for this simple question.

Comment: why did you try then?

Comment: It's a Q&A website you know...